# Cannot Run HITMAN on Ubuntu

Tags: games, steam

Why doesn't HITMAN support Ubuntu? What can I do to play HITMAN? I already reported the issue to the developer but cannot receive any response for a long time.
[image]

The following is the specifications of my computer.

```
OS        : Ubuntu 17.04 x86_64 
Model     : Z97X-UD3H 
Kernel    : 4.10.0-19-generic 
Shell     : bash 4.4.5 
Resolution: 1920x1080, 1440x900 
CPU       : Intel i5-4460 (4) @ 3.4GHz 
GPU       : Intel Integrated Graphics 
GPU       : AMD Radeon R7 370 
Memory    : 4321MiB / 11874MiB
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PC does not meet the minimum system requirements for the software:

```
OS              : Ubuntu 16.04 or Steam OS 2.0
Processor       : Intel Core i5-2500K/AMD FX-8350
Memory          : 8 GB RAM
Graphics        : Nvidia GeForce GTX 680/AMD R9 270X graphics card or better*
Storage         : 67 GB available space
Additional Notes: *NVIDIA graphics cards require driver version 375.26. AMD graphics cards require MESA 13.0.3 or better. Intel graphics cards will not be supported on release.
```

Source: http://store.steampowered.com/app/236870/

There's no point in complaining to the developers.

Comment: Therefore, I can play HITMAN after replacing the graphic card?

Comment: Maybe. For games we usually say that the *de facto* minimum requirements are the recommended ones, otherwise the experience will be subpar. Check those in the provided link.